# PHP, error_log('the message'); how to retrieve and show the message in the browser?

Tags: php, error-log

I rephrased the original post (see below).
PHP 7.4 on XAMPP.
I am working on a basic login page. I want to use the error logging system to smuggle user-generated error notes such as 'Login failure'; next
I want to retrieve and show it in the browser  in the following format: date-time-zone-message - essentially a line of the trace from the php_error_log file, (without a file name, and error type) such as:
**[22-Jun-2020 13:43:49 Europe/Berlin] Login failure**

1. when I use `error_log('Login Failure')` function, it writes to the php_error_log file OK but when I want to show the trace in the browser via   `$php_errormsg` variable (depreciated)  or `error_get_last()` function it does not work.
   However both $php_errormsg and error_get_last() work fine for automatic errors such as undefined variable.
2. so I found another function `trigger_error()` and this one works both with the file and the browser and I can use the above-mentioned ways of retrieving errors (Notice: Login Failure in /my-file.php on line 21)
   Still, I do not know how to print out the date-time-zone part of the trace.

How the line of 'trace' in php_error_log file is assembled?

How exactly all the above works?

Is there any good reference explaining the error logging system across PHP evolution?

=========

1st post.

How do I retrieve and show PHP error_log messages, in the browser? (XAMPP stack)

that is my intended output:

**[11-Feb-2016 15:52:03 Europe/Berlin] Success!!**

1. I know where the php_error_log file is located.
2. I know that the function `error_log('Success!!');` writes to this file when used in the script.
3. I DO NOT know how to show the same message, on the screen, in the browser together with the login form. Any suggestion?

I tried: `print_r(error_get_last());`

This shows the automatic errors such as an undefined variable but does not output messages added in the script by `error_log()`.

Is there a separate error handling system? I studied docs but to no avail!
Any good reference to read?

Comment: Have you checked? https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php

Comment: `echo` or `print` ?

Comment: `error_log()` writes to the error log. If you just want to output a message use `echo`, `print` or `print_r`.

Comment: [error_log()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.error-log.php) has several arguments to fine-tune the destination and the location of the error file can be customised too. But it isn't clear what problem you're trying to solve. What's your ultimate goal?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you need to use try/catch blocks in order to return the error message to the browser.

Comment: The internal error trigger functionality really isn't meant to be used for user-facing error handling. Especially when using `error_get_last`, which only returns the very last error triggered; the more complex your code gets over time, there may be more errors being triggered between the one you want to be user facing and the time you try to fetch that message, breaking your logic.

Comment: Yes, I get that; in my case, it is just for learning, and the script is very simple and basic and the developer is the user, what is wrong in seeing an error on the page as opposed in the log file? What I've learned so far - provided I get it right - manual/custom/user errors are handled differently than automatic errors. Maybe by knowing how the trace (for the php-error-log file) is assembled I could direct its flow to the screen not the file and parse it more intelligently, as opposed to what I am doing now which is trying random stuff.

Comment: so just for simplicity: how exactly the php-error-log gets assembled? how to parse and display data from the php_error_log trace?